# XML and Process list imports, comparison, and action to kill processes for Adobe CC Conflict List

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, adobe, ps

Adobe gives me an XML list of what processes will conflict with each installer build, but no way to automate the use of such file to end those tasks.

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. Import the Conflict Process list from the XML file that they generate,
2. Compare with the list of current running processes,
3. Kill those that match along the way.

I'm fairly new to Powershell but canusually figure my way around.  This one has me scratching my head though...

The array from the XML file comes in fine, the same seems true for the running processes array, but the comparing of the two and killing of the process when matching, doesn't seem to be working...

Below I'll add my code, and a sample xml file that adobe's installer building generated.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Hopefully it's something stupid and I'm 90% the way there, but I'm not sure.  The script generates no errors, but doesn't do anything either, so, yeah...

Thanks in Advance for any tips or other souls seeking to make a fix for this problem that can complete what I've begun...

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path .\ConflictingProcessList.xml
$ConflictProcesses = $XmlDocument.ConflictingProcessList.Product.conflictingProcesses.ConflictingProcess
$ProcessList = gwmi Win32_Process

foreach ($ProcessDisplayName in $ConflictProcesses)
{
    foreach ($name in $ProcessList)
    {
        Where-Object { $ConflictProcesses.RelativePath -contains $ProcessList.ProcessName } | % { Stop-Process ($ProcessList.ProcessID) }
    }
    $ProcessList = gwmi Win32_Process
}
```

Here is a Sample XML, for the Acrobat Pro 2018 CC installer:

```
<ConflictingProcessList>
    <Product>
        <name>Creative Cloud</name>
        <conflictingProcesses>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>PDapp.exe</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath>%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\CCP\CreativeCloudPackager.exe</RelativePath>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>Adobe Application Manager (Updater).exe</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath>%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\UWA\Adobe Application Manager (Updater).exe</RelativePath>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>PDapp.exe</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath>%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\core\PDapp.exe</RelativePath>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>AAM Updates Notifier.exe</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath>%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\UWA\AAM Updates Notifier.exe</RelativePath>
            </ConflictingProcess>
        </conflictingProcesses>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <name>Acrobat DC</name>
        <conflictingProcesses>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>Adobe Acrobat DC</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath>[INSTALLDIR]\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe</RelativePath>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>Microsoft Outlook</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath/>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>Adobe Acrobat X</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath>[INSTALLDIR]\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe</RelativePath>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>Microsoft PowerPoint</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath/>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>Visio</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath/>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>Microsoft Excel</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath/>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>Adobe Acrobat 2015</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath>[INSTALLDIR]\Acrobat 2015\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe</RelativePath>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>Adobe Acrobat XI</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath>[INSTALLDIR]\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe</RelativePath>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>MS Project</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath/>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>Microsoft Word</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath/>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>Adobe Acrobat 2017</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath>[INSTALLDIR]\Acrobat 2017\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe</RelativePath>
            </ConflictingProcess>
            <ConflictingProcess>
                <ProcessDisplayName>AutoCAD</ProcessDisplayName>
                <RelativePath/>
            </ConflictingProcess>
        </conflictingProcesses>
    </Product>
</ConflictingProcessList>
```

Comment: Apart from a few mistakes, your approach seems to only take into account the `RelativePath` attribute from the XML file - what about the processes that only have a `ProcessDisplayName` attribute specified?

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I guess I'd have to query some other source to try to tie the ProcessDisplayName to a Process exe from some other source.  Maybe a wmi call to the Add and Remove Programs list, I'm not sure.  Adobe really gave a half-baked starting point here...  Will have to think on that a bit.

Comment: I'm thinking some use of get-process -Name, comparing to the ProcessDisplayName variable but it would have to add wildcard on each side, and kill the process if found, ignoring errors where not found.

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach` loops are redundant, as you never actually reference the `$ProcessDisplayName` or `$name` local variables. Additionally, the inner pipeline (starting with `Where-Object`) won't ever result in anything, because you don't actually feed any data to it.

I would suggest iterating over the `$ConflictProcesses` and kill any matching process like so:

```
foreach($ConflictProcess in $ConflictProcesses){
    # Extract file name
    $FileName = $ConflictProcess.RelativePath |Split-Path -Leaf

    # Now grab the processes with that file name and kill them 
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Process |Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $FileName } |Stop-Process -Id {$_.ProcessId}
}
```

Comment: I tested that code (nice btw), and got 7 lines of errors returned, presumably for the 7 items that had no relativepath entry.  Do I need to include a command to continue on error, or add a check sort of like, where not null... ?